# MySQL locking priorities

Tags: mysql, concurrency

If there is an item that has a read lock on a table for a whole minute, then other items can still read that same table uninterrupted.

So I can have this timeline

A makes a read lock for a minute
B, C, D, E ... and many more still read from that table without a problem

But say that T asks for a *write* lock. T has to wait.. It seems that U V W are all waiting for T,, even though U V W are only asking for read locks and T has not actually aquired it's lock yet.

Is it possible to disable this First In First Out sort of prioritizing and to give read locks higher priority than write locks?

**Edit:** Perhaps there is some sort of low priority switch that I can put on my update commands? I would like for it to be synchronous (so a thread can wait till it is done, even though it is low priority).

Comment: I don't know if this is possible, but in a busy database I would think it would lead to a high chance of starvation for write locks since they can never be obtained if there are constant read locks required.

Comment: We are talking about `MyISAM`, aren't we?

Comment: @tloach There are not usually constant read locks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a way to make updates low priority without sending them to a separate thread.

Change one of

```
UPDATE bob ...
INSERT INTO bob ...
DELETE FROM bob;
LOCK TABLE bob WRITE;
```

to

```
UPDATE LOW_PRIORITY bob ...
INSERT LOW_PRIORITY INTO bob ...
DELETE LOW_PRIORITY FROM bob;
LOCK TABLE bob LOW_PRIORITY WRITE;
```

Answer (score 7):

> But say that T asks for a write lock. T has to wait.. It seems that U V W are all waiting for T,, even though U V W are only asking for read locks and T has not actually aquired it's lock yet

Write locks are assigned higher priority than read locks.

This means that `T` will only have to wait for `A` to complete, and `U`, `V` and `W` will be queued after `B`, `C`, `D`, and `E`.

Actually, read and write locks are held in the separate queues, the latter being of higher priority.

In your case, the request will be executed in the following order:

```
A
T
B C D U V W
```

, everything after `T` being executed concurrently.

From the [**docs**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/internal-locking.html):

> Table updates are given higher priority than table retrievals. Therefore, when a lock is released, the lock is made available to the requests in the write lock queue and then to the requests in the read lock queue. This ensures that updates to a table are not “starved” even if there is heavy `SELECT` activity for the table. However, if you have many updates for a table, `SELECT` statements wait until there are no more updates.

If you want the writing transaction to wait until there are no pending reads, you should explicitly issue

```
LOCK TABLES mytable LOW_PRIORITY WRITE
```

prior to the `INSERT`, and do not forget to do

```
UNLOCK TABLES
```

afterwards.

Comment: Can you make a lower priority update that is *not* asynchronous, or would that still have the same issue? What about a low priority one that *is* asynchronous?